# ANTLR4: How to parse non-root node?

Tags: java, antlr, grammar

Given a grammar

```
script: statement*;
statement: do | check;
do: 'do';
check: 'check';
```

How can I parse a non-root node? In other words,

```
ScriptParser sp = new ScriptParser();
StatementContext sc = sp.parse<StatementContext>("do");
```

I simplified above example.

A solution is to make all nodes root nodes like

```
rootNode: script | statement | do | check;
```

but I don't want that as it pollutes my grammar and is a maintenance nightmare (whenever the grammar adds/removes a node, the rootnode must be updated, which is error-prone).
Another solution is to write another derived grammar with the rootnode specification. This would not pollute the main grammar, but still has the maintenance issue.

Is there a better way to do this? I'd like to use many of my nodes (***Context classes) and pass them into constructors of my domain model classes.

Comment: Which ANLTR version? In ANTLR 3, you explicitly state what is the entry point by calling the method with rule's name, e.g. `parser.script()` or `parser.do()`.

Comment: ANTLR4 (4.7). I updated the title.

Comment: Isn't "do" a valid value of "script" in your grammar? What specifically do you want? To limit parsing to only check if a string is a valid "check"?

Comment: I want to parse non-root nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Jiri Tousek! The answer is indeed

```
ScriptParser sp = new ScriptParser();
StatementContext sc = sp.statement();
```